# Movable pattern with repeat?

Tags: html, canvas

I have started learning Canvas in HTML5 and I have a question.

I want create a movable pattern with repeat. (Something like background-position and background-repeat in CSS.)

How can I do this?

I need this to create an animated background for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few ways to achieve this the you could use `putImageData` but you would suffer some performance loss, the best method is to use `drawImage`. Also note the 2nd method has the code to make it go either from left to right, or right to left.

http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/bgscroll/scrolldrawimage.html

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    canvasTemp = document.createElement("canvas"),
    scrollImg = new Image(),
    tempContext = canvasTemp.getContext("2d"),
    imgWidth = 0,
    imgHeight =0,
    imageData = {},
    canvasWidth = 600,
    canvasHeight = 240,
    scrollVal = 0,
    speed =2;

    scrollImg.src = "citybg.png";
    scrollImg.onload = loadImage;

function loadImage(){
    imgWidth = scrollImg.width,
    imgHeight = scrollImg.height;
    canvasTemp.width = imgWidth;
    canvasTemp.height =  imgHeight;    
    render();                
}

function render(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

    if(scrollVal >= canvasWidth){
        scrollVal = 0;
    }

    scrollVal+=speed;                   
    ctx.drawImage(scrollImg,canvasWidth-scrollVal,0,scrollVal,imgHeight, 0, 0, scrollVal,imgHeight);
    ctx.drawImage(scrollImg,scrollVal,0,imgWidth, imgHeight);

     // To go the other way instead
     ctx.drawImage(scrollImg,-scrollVal,0,imgWidth, imgHeight);
     ctx.drawImage(scrollImg,canvasWidth-scrollVal,0,imgWidth, imgHeight);

    setTimeout(function(){render();},10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.
First Create one function for moving and trigger that function using setInterval() 
setInterval method is window object for timing event. it executes a function or an expression over and over again in a specified number of milliseconds.

You can refer post.I created sample snake game using html5 canvas and audio. 
http://www.arungudelli.com/2012/10/html5-canvas-example-snake-game.html

Answer (score 0):

You can animate a background pattern with CSS3.  You can overlay additional canvas elements on top of the animation and control the animation with JavaScript by toggling classes.

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/UKwxy/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/UKwxy/show))

```
body {
    background:url('http://pattern8.com/images/pattern-thumbs/pattern8-pattern-61c.png');    
}

body.scrollbg {
    -webkit-animation: scrollbg   6s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1) infinite;
    ...(moz,ms,o vendor prefixes)...
    animation: scrollbg   6s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scrollbg {
      0% { background-position: left  top,    left  top; }
     25% { background-position: right top,    left  bottom; }
     50% { background-position: right bottom, right bottom; }
     75% { background-position: left  bottom, right top; }
    100% { background-position: left  top,    left  top; }
}
```

see also:

- http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/pure-css3-animated-clouds-background
- http://lab.simurai.com/space-cacss/
- http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/demos/css3-animated-vignette-buttons/
- http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#progress
- http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/css3-slick-progress-bars-demo.html

[support is widely available (sans IE < 10)](http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframe)

for IE support you could use something like this [canvas animation template](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/)